# Can't connect to localhost in Android

Tags: android, networking, connection, project, android-volley

I have an android project which I made in my desktop .I connect to the internet over wifi .But when I run the same project in laptop I cant connect to internet over my mobile data operator. Where's the problem?

[I found "No internet connection" as volleyError](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/15272293/)

Comment: what do you exactly want to do..is it that you want to connect to the localhost on your computer from your mobile?. Can you explain the requirement a little more clearly, I might be able to help out.

Comment: I want to access the localhost stored in my laptop from my android device for testing an app.What is the appropriate method for this???

Comment: refer to the answer below

Comment: did you try the steps?

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is by using port forwarding:

1. Connect your device and open chrome on both your mobile and laptop browser.
2. On the URL tab, type chrome://inspect
3. Click on port forwarding and add a new row, with port as 8888 and IP as localhost:8080.[image]
4. Now in your android application code, replace localhost:8080 with localhost:8888.

Basically now on 8888 your mobile will the connect to the computers localhost.
Note: Make sure that chrome is open on both your laptop and the device. And when you type chrome://inspect you should be able to see the device you have attached.

Refer to this for more help: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Also add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to your Androidmanifest.xml